# Microsoft SQL server management studio 18 commandline replacement

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, sql-server, sql

I have created an SQL file for my SQL server. When I double-click on that, Microsoft SQL server Management Studio 18 is opened, username and password are asked, the query is opened and I can launch it.

I would like to do this automatically. Is there a commandline tool for this? (I already checked, I don't have `mssql-cli` on my computer)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [sqlcmd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) it is part of SQL Server so hopefully you will already have it installed.

See [this other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/656666/is-sqlcmd-part-of-the-db-engine-or-client-tools/656670#656670) regarding which part of the SQL Server installation it is included in.
In summary it is included as part of Management Tools - Basic, but you can also install it separately if required.